# In what ways does C++ inheritance order affect a constructor?

Tags: c++, inheritance, inherited-constructors

If I define a structure that inherits from multiple other structures, how does the order that I list them in affect something like this:

```
struct D: C,B{
    D(): B(), C(){...}
};
```

Simple question, but thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of construction depends on the sequence of inheritance. Initialization order doesn't matter. GCC actually issues warning in this case.

> In constructor 'D::D()':
>
> main.cpp:16:17: warning: base 'B' will be initialized after
> [-Wreorder]
>
> ```
>  D(): B(), C(){
>              ^
> ```
>
> main.cpp:16:17: warning:   base 'C' [-Wreorder]
>
> main.cpp:16:5: warning:   when initialized here [-Wreorder]
>
> ```
>  D(): B(), C(){
> ```

It is clearly specified in the standard as well. From section 12.6.2 Initializing bases and members

> Initialization shall proceed in the following order:
>
> — First, and only
> for the constructor of the most derived class as described below,
> virtual base classes shall be initialized in the order they appear on
> a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic graph of
> base classes, where “left-to-right” is the order of appearance of the
> base class names in the derived class base-specifier- list .
> — Then, **direct base classes shall be initialized in declaration order as they
> appear in the base-specifier-list (regardless of the order of the
> mem-initializers).**